# Scrapy pagination issues - new to this stuff

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to make a scrapy bot that utilizes pagination but having no success...

The bot crawls through all of the links on the first page one but never goes on to the next page. I have read a ton of different threads and I cant figure this out at all. I am very new to web scraping to please feel free to hammer the crap out of my code.

```
    import time
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    #from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
    from tutorial.items import TutorialItem


    #from scrapy_tutorial.items import ScrapyTutorialItem

    class raytheonJobsPageSpider(CrawlSpider):

        name = "raytheonJobsStart"
        allowed_domains = ["jobs.raytheon.com"]
        start_urls = [
            "https://jobs.raytheon.com/search-jobs"
        ]

        rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="next"]',)), callback='parse_listings',follow=True), )

        def parse_start_url(self, response):
            '''
            Crawl start URLs
            '''

            return self.parse_listings(response)

        def parse_listings(self, response):
            '''
            Extract data from listing pages
            '''

            sel = Selector(response)
            jobs = response.xpath(
                '//*[@id="search-results-list"]/ul/*/a/@href'
            ).extract()
            nextLink = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]').extract()
            print "This is just the next page link - ",nextLink

            for job_url in jobs:
                job_url = self.__normalise(job_url)
                job_url = self.__to_absolute_url(response.url, job_url)

                yield Request(job_url, callback=self.parse_details)

        def parse_details(self, response):
            '''
            Extract data from details pages
            '''


            sel = Selector(response)
            job = sel.xpath('//*[@id="content"]')
            item = TutorialItem()
            # Populate job fields
            item['title'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/h1/text()').extract()
            jobTitle=job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/h1/text()').extract()
            item['reqid'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/span[1]/text()').extract()
            item['location'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/span[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['applink'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/a[2]/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/div').extract()
            item['clearance'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div/*/text()').extract()
            #item['page_url'] = response.url
            item = self.__normalise_item(item, response.url)
            time.sleep(1)
            return item

        def __normalise_item(self, item, base_url):
            '''
            Standardise and format item fields
            '''

            # Loop item fields to sanitise data and standardise data types
            for key, value in vars(item).values()[0].iteritems():
                item[key] = self.__normalise(item[key])

            # Convert job URL from relative to absolute URL
            #item['job_url'] = self.__to_absolute_url(base_url, item['job_url'])

            return item

        def __normalise(self, value):
            print self,value
            # Convert list to string
            value = value if type(value) is not list else ' '.join(value)
            # Trim leading and trailing special characters (Whitespaces, newlines, spaces, tabs, carriage returns)
            value = value.strip()

            return value

        def __to_absolute_url(self, base_url, link):
            '''
            Convert relative URL to absolute URL
            '''

            import urlparse

            link = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)

            return link

        def __to_int(self, value):
            '''
            Convert value to integer type
            '''

            try:
                value = int(value)
            except ValueError:
                value = 0

            return value

        def __to_float(self, value):
            '''
            Convert value to float type
            '''

            try:
                value = float(value)
            except ValueError:
                value = 0.0

            return value
```

Comment: It seems your URL is using some AJAX/Javascript requests for pagination. Please try Java script rendering using splash: http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-tutorial.html

Comment: I will read up on that and see if I can figure it out, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how to use Splash... trying to learn it, this seems pretty advanced.

Comment: What i need this spider to do is crawl the first page of links which it does, then I need it to go onto the next page which is where it fails. I dont even know if its using the Rule portion of the script...

Comment: You cannot find direct link to next page. Scrapy will work only for the links that are visible in HTML source. And again in your case JavaScript rendering is required to load next page. You have to use `splash` or  `selenium` or `phantomjs` in your code to navigation to next pages.

Comment: Thanks for at least pointing me in the right direction, some sort of example might have been helpful.. oh well.

Comment: The internet appears to be filled with half-examples and horrible tutorials (way too simplified)... I would like to try selenium and all I need it to do is click NEXT.. nothing else, just click next. This is turning into a crazy task for something that appears to be so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need PhantomJS or Splash.

By inspecting the AJAX calls I found that they are loading jobs via AJAX calls to [this URL](https://jobs.raytheon.com/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&Latitude=&Longitude=&ShowRadius=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search%20Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search%20Filters&SortCriteria=5&SortDirection=1&SearchType=5&CategoryFacetTerm=&CategoryFacetType=&LocationFacetTerm=&LocationFacetType=&KeywordType=&LocationType=&LocationPath=&OrganizationIds=&CurrentPage=1)

You can see `CurrentPage` parameter at the end of URL.

And the result is returned in JSON format, and all jobs are on the key named `results`

I created a project on my side and I created fully 100% working code for you. Here is link to that in github, just download and run it ... you dont have to do anything at all :P

Download whole working project fomr here https://github.com/mani619cash/raytheon_pagination

Basic logic is here
class RaytheonspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):

```
name = "raytheonJobsStart"
page = 180
ajaxURL = "https://jobs.raytheon.com/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&Latitude=&Longitude=&ShowRadius=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=5&SortDirection=1&SearchType=5&CategoryFacetTerm=&CategoryFacetType=&LocationFacetTerm=&LocationFacetType=&KeywordType=&LocationType=&LocationPath=&OrganizationIds=&CurrentPage="

def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(self.ajaxURL + str(self.page), callback=self.parse_listings)

def parse_listings(self, response):
    resp = json.loads(response.body)

    response = Selector(text = resp['results'])

    jobs = response.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-list"]/ul/*/a/@href').extract()
    if jobs:
        for job_url in jobs:
            job_url = "https://jobs.raytheon.com" + self.__normalise(job_url)
            #job_url = self.__to_absolute_url(response.url, job_url)
            yield Request(url=job_url, callback=self.parse_details)
    else:
        raise CloseSpider("No more pages... exiting...")

    # go to next page...
    self.page = self.page + 1
    yield Request(self.ajaxURL + str(self.page), callback=self.parse_listings)
```

Comment: 2016-12-02 16:58:23 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-12-02 16:58:23 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 14060,
 'downloader/request_count': 16,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 16,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1790351,
 'downloader/response_count': 16,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 16,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 16, 58, 23, 625836),
 'item_scraped_count': 15,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 32,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 16,

Comment: 'scheduler/dequeued': 16,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 16,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 16,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 16,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 16, 58, 7, 34569)}
2016-12-02 16:58:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Comment: It still stops after the first page... What am I doing wrong here.. 

scrapy runspider raytheonspider.py

Comment: It looks like you defined "page = 1" but I dont see how that increments.

Comment: @JasonBaker I edited my answer and also I pushed latest changes on github as well ... sorry the page was not being incremented.... Now you can set `page = 1` to see if it works

Comment: I have deliberately set `page = 180` because there are total 182 pages on that site ...

Comment: also use `scrapy crawl raytheonJobsStart` command to run it ... not `scrapy runspider raytheonspider.py`

Answer (score 0):

Change

`restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="next"]',))` to

`restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="next"]',))`

If this not working then do a recursive call to parse_listings function

```
def parse_listings(self, response):
        '''
        Extract data from listing pages
        '''

        sel = Selector(response)
        jobs = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="search-results-list"]/ul/*/a/@href'
        ).extract()
        nextLink = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]').extract()
        print "This is just the next page link - ",nextLink

        for job_url in jobs:
            job_url = self.__normalise(job_url)
            job_url = self.__to_absolute_url(response.url, job_url)

            yield Request(job_url, callback=self.parse_details)

       yield Request(pagination link here, callback=self.parse_listings)
```

I am on mobile so cant type code. I hope the logic i told you makes sense

Comment: I will give this a try when I get home from work and start working Job #2 tonight.

Comment: I tried this but from what the above comments say by Prabhakar, I need to find a way to parse out the javascript.. So, here we go, another long few nights figuring out javascript and how to use selenium, phantomjs or splash.. YAY........................